# multiple tomcats on same port but different local IP

Tags: tomcat

I have windows 7 hosts file like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.78.128  cloudera-vm440
127.0.0.61      tomcat61
127.0.0.71      tomcat71
```

With this I thought I could bring up two tomcats on different local IP but same port 8080 etc.

This does not work.  I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:430)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:623)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
```

Is this the way it is or can I do something about it?

Answer (score 0):

You have two sockets attempting to listen on the same IP and port. Basically, two sockets are trying to connect to the exact same place. This is impossible. Let's say for example my IP address is 192.168.0.235. My 'home' IP is 127.0.0.1. These identify the same actual network address: my computer. Now if I'm using port 8080 for both, I've just attempted to use the same address twice.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost 
192.168.78.128 cloudera-vm440 
127.0.0.61 tomcat61 
127.0.0.71 tomcat71

I used tomcatt61 for one and tomcat71 for the others. These are two different IP's. I also tried by binding additional static IPs. Same problem. I thought the port is subordinate to only IP. Looks like not. Is it that I have to create a virtual adapter like what VMWare does?

Comment: @RangaNathan That mess was illegibile in your question, until I fixed it just now, and it's illegible here too. Don't post stuff that needs formatting in comments, and when you post it in a question or an answer, *format* it. No wonder you never got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just writing a hosts file isn't sufficient. You need to configure the Connector in Tomcat to specify the listen address. By default, a Tomcat Connector will listen at 0.0.0.0.